# I can't get my program to read the second line of a text document

Tags: vb.net

Alright so I am trying to make my program read a specific line of a text file. I created two labels, designated one as TheFileName and the other as TheText. Everything works, except I can not figure out how to make it read the second line, and only the second line.

Code:

Dim Rlo As New IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\RobloxRecruitV1\RobloxRecruitV1\bin\Debug\" & TheFileName.Text & ".txt")

TheText.Text = Rlo.ReadLine(2)

Comment: I assume this is VB.NET and not VB6?

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim Rlo As New IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\RobloxRecruitV1\RobloxRecruitV1\bin\Debug\" & TheFileName.Text & ".txt")

Dim firstLine As String
'read first line
firstLine = Rlo.ReadLine()
'read secondline
TheText.Text = Rlo.ReadLine()
```